# Override or create new engine in Flask-Migrate migration

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm running a migration which inserts ~160k records into a PostgreSQL database. This is taking between 40-50 seconds to complete. Unfortunately, this breaks the build process in CircleCI and therefore makes every build after it fail. I also have no direct access to the database and am forced to do this in a migration.

Package versions, if relevant:

- Python: 3.7.2
- Flask: 1.1.2,
- Flask-SQLAlchemy: 2.5.1
- psycopg2-binary: 2.8.6
- SQLAlchemy: 1.3.23

I've been reading about the `executemany='values'` flag on `create_engine` (`engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@host/dbname", xecutemany_mode='values_plus_batch')`, for example) and I'd like to use it for this migration, since it seems it would help, but if I do so, the process simply hangs (inspecting PostgreSQL's process list hints at the session being locked on the first `insert` statement, but I have no idea how to close it):

```py
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session


def upgrade():
    list_of_objects_to_insert = get_and_process_objects_from_csv_file()  # This returns a list of SQLAlchemy ORM objects, ready to insert.
    new_engine = create_engine(op.get_bind().engine.url, executemany_mode='values')
    session = Session(new_engine)
    session.bulk_save_objects(list_of_objects_to_insert)
    session.commit()
    print('Inserted all records from bulk list') # This never gets printed
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks in advance.